# Migration Fail From Bazaar To Git: fatal: Path xxx not in branch

Tags: git, bazaar

I'm struggling with a migration from Bazzar to Git. When I execute export/import command below, it crashes because of the error. But there is no instruction what should I do next. Could anyone please tell me how to resolve it?

Execute command

```
% bzr fast-export --export-marks=marks.bzr ../trunk | git fast-import --export-marks=marks.git
```

Error

```
fatal: Path xxx not in branch
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_14082
bzr: broken pipe
```

- Other information
  The number of revision is over 30,000.

Found a similar situation, but it haven't resolved the problem yet.
[git fast-export format and spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757383/git-fast-export-format-and-spaces)

Tried with several options, but every command failed, too.

```
% bzr fast-export --plain --rewrite-tag-names --export-marks=marks.bzr ../trunk | git fast-import --export-marks=marks.git --force
% bzr fast-export --baseline --rewrite-tag-names --export-marks=marks.bzr ../trunk | git fast-import --export-marks=marks.git
% bzr fast-export --rewrite-tag-names --export-marks=marks.bzr ../trunk | git fast-import --export-marks=marks.git --force
```

Comment: Now trying to the other way. 'git-remote-bzr' https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-bzr and 'bzr-git' https://launchpad.net/bzr-git/+download

Comment: I got an error with git-remote-bzr, so issued on a github. https://github.com/felipec/git-remote-bzr/issues/14

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with the `dpush`command.
I successfully exported many small and large repositories (not 30k rev indeed) with this.

Just two steps:

**Step1: Create a Git bare repository**
From bazaar, create a Git bare repository with the `init` command.

```
bzr init --format=git-bare
```

**Step2: Export your project**
Push you project in this newly created Git repository with the `dpush` command.

```
bzr dpush myfolder/myNewGitrepo.git
```

*note*: `myNewGitrepo.git` was created in step 1 of course.

Comment: Unfortunately got error and failed. Here is the part of stack trace. It's ok for me just to skip such a invalid(cannot export) commit, but is there any idea? Should I do hack the lib? **File "/usr/local/Cellar/bazaar/2.6.0/libexec/bzrlib/inventory.py", line 1868, in __getitem__   raise errors.NoSuchId(self, file_id) NoSuchId: The file id "None" is not present in the tree <bzrlib.inventory.CHKInventory object at 0x11ec22cd0>.**

Comment: Found a similar bug report, but no work around so far... https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-git/+bug/937235

Comment: bzr-git doesn't help, too :( Now checking git-bzr-ng... https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr-git/+bug/1460459